# How to notify the outer coroutine when destroying an inner coroutine?

Tags: c++, exception, memory-leaks, coroutine, c++20

```
task<> f2()
{
    struct Awaiter
    {
        bool await_ready() { return false; }    
        void await_resume() {}    
        void await_suspend(auto h_coro)
        {
            std::thread([=]() mutable
            {
                if (any_error_occur())
                {
                    h_coro.destroy();
                }
            }).detach();
        }
    };

    co_await Awaiter();
    // If any error occur, below won't be executed
    do_many_things(); 
}

task<> f1()
{
    auto p = new char[4096];
    co_await f2(); // won't be resumed if any error occur
    // memory leak if any error occur!
    delete[] p;
}

int main()
{
    f1();
    while (true);
}
```

**How to notify the outer coroutine when destroying an inner coroutine?**

Comment: If any_error_occur(), the coroutine created by the call to f2 is destroyed. But that does not implies anything for the awaiter used for the evaluation of `co_await f2()`. Could you provide the definition of `task`?

Comment: `cppcoro::task` see: https://github.com/lewissbaker/cppcoro

Comment: I will not see it... you know you should post a minimal and compilable exemple... Or you add a tag for this specific library and include the necessary files...